# QlikView Expression that ignores some selections and contains where explicit values

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis, qlik-expression

I have a basic expression `SUM(value)`.

I want to modify this expression so it does 2 things:

Ignores all list box selections except one (yearperiod) and contains explicit where conditions.

Pseudo expected expression:

```
(SUM(value) Where category = 'abc'/SUM(TOTAL value Where category = 'abc' OR 'xyz' (NOT AFFECTED BY yearperiod))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using set analysis.

```
SUM({1<yearperiod  = $:: yearperiod, Category = {'abc'} >}Value)/SUM(TOTAL {1<yearperiod  = $:: yearperiod, Category = {'abc','xyz'} >}Value)
```